# Rotring 0.6 ArtPen alternative?

Tags: tools, art, fine-arts, calligraphy

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good calligraphy pen that could serve as an alternative for the discontinued Rotring 0.6 ArtPen?

Comment: I think a "good alternative" would be entirely based on who is using the pen.

Comment: Could you please describe what you were doing with the  original pen and why you liked it? That way, we might be able to give good answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manuscript sells entry-level pens, as does Speedball in the U.S.

Lamy does nice pens, incl. a line of calligraphy pens like to the Rotring Artpens: http://www.lamyusa.com/lamy_fountain_L15_joy.php

Unfortunately, their narrowest nib is 1.1mm wide. Best option would be to get a broad nib and grind it down (or have a nib Meister do it).